# Beginner in R - Writing loops and functions

Tags: r

I am new to R (I only started learning a few weeks ago) and I need some help with a question on my homework. I have asked my professor several times already and mostly that's resulted in me being more confused.

The question is as follows:

Recall that the Taylor expansion of log(1+x) is:

log(x+1) = sum((-1)^(i+1)*x^i/i)

How many terms do you need to get within 10^(−6) of the correct solution when x = 0.99?

My professor gave me some hints:

- n should not be equal to length of x. n should be figured out from the loop. It is the iteration number of the last loop.
- the condition of the while loop should depend on the difference between the approximated value and the true value of the function. Not on n any more.
- in each iteration, you need to calculate (-1)^(i+1)*x^2/i and add it to the sum of the previous iterations so that you accumulate the sum. Check the example about factorial function in class.
- You should include your while loop in a function. The function should have a single argument x.

I'm not asking for anyone to give me the answer, but I would appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

Below is some code of what I've tried. It is incomplete still and I'm not sure what is missing:

```
taylorexp <- function(x){
    i = 1
    approximation = 1

    while((log(1+x) - approximation) > 10^(-6)){
        z=sum((-1)^(i+1)*x^i/i)
        i=i+1
    }
    return(i)
}

taylorexp(0.99)
```

Comment: some hints: (1) what is _the correct answer_ that you are trying to approximate? (2) what is the approximation with 1 term? (3) what is the approximation with 2 terms? (3) what is the approximation with `n` terms?

Comment: Hi there, :) it would be infinitely more helpful to potential answerers of this question if you were able to post what you have tried, and what has/hasn't worked so far.

Comment: Hello! This is what I have so far, which I realize is incomplete):                      
taylorexp <- function(x){
    i = 1
    approximation = 1

    while((log(1+x) - approximation) > 10^(-6)){
        z=sum((-1)^(i+1)*x^i/i)
        i=i+1
    }
    return(i)
}

taylorexp(0.99)

Comment: One thing you're not doing in the function is augmenting the `approximation` object.  You have `z` equal to the sum of a single term, which will return just that term, you will need to add that to the running `approximation`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `repeat`

```
s <- 0
i <- 1
x <- 0.99
repeat{
  if (abs(log(1 + x) - s) <= 1e-6) break
  s <- s + (-1)**(i + 1) * x**i / i
  i <- i + 1
}
```

or with `while`

```
s <- 0
i <- 1
x <- 0.99
while(abs(log(1 + x) - s) > 1e-6) {
  s <- s + (-1)**(i + 1) * x**i / i
  i <- i + 1
}
```

and we will get

```
> i
[1] 661
```

---

**Update**
You can wrap all the required information in a list as the output of function `taylorexp`, e.g.,

```
taylorexp <- function(x, tol) {
  s <- 0
  i <- 1
  while (abs(log(1 + x) - s) > tol) {
    s <- s + (-1)**(i + 1) * x**i / i
    i <- i + 1
  }
  list(approx = s, err = log(1 + x) - s, n = i)
}
```

such that

```
> taylorexp(0.99,1e-6)
$approx
[1] 0.6881336

$err
[1] 9.911419e-07

$n
[1] 661


> taylorexp(0.99,1e-7)
$approx
[1] 0.6881345

$err
[1] 9.966883e-08

$n
[1] 863
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I asked me professor about this code and she replied the following:                             
1. The difference between the approximation and the true value can be positive or negative. 
2. You need to accumulate terms to get the sum. You cannot do it using the sum function.
3. You need to return both n and the difference.                                                                 
I'm not sure what she is talking about or how to do what she wants?

Comment: @Tatiana Please check my update. I believe it is the thing you want

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I spent some time working on this the other day based on your help and I got a similar code, which yielded the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Update:

```
taylor = function(x,n){ 
  out = 0 
  for(i in 1:n){
    out = out + ((-1)^(i+1))*(x^i/i)
 }
 out
}
true_val = log(1 + 0.99)
true_val

approx_val = taylor(0.99, 10)
approx_val
```